# Reduce height from top and bottom of div (not just bottom)

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with an `<img>` inside of it and am making the image's height decrease to the size of the div.

When I decrease the size of the `<div>`, it removes some of the bottom of the image as it's inside a container with a fixed height and the overflow is hidden, which is alright - as that's what I want it to do. However, I would also like to remove some of the top of the image also.

```html
<p>What the image first looks like:</p>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/69/Stop_sign(standard).svg" width="140" height="150">
<p>What the image looks like after removing some of it by putting it inside the div:</p>
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 140px; height: 120px;">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/69/Stop_sign(standard).svg" width="140" height="150">
</div>

<p>But... I would like to remove some of the top of the stop sign also - not just the bottom!</p>
```

If you run the code snippet, you can see an example of what I mean.

*JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6rqzy5pL/*

Comment: How are you decreasing the height of image?

Comment: @VivekAthalye By putting it inside a container with a fixed height and `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>What the image first looks like:</p>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/69/Stop_sign(standard).svg" width="140" height="150">
<p>What the image looks like after removing some of it by putting it inside the div:</p>
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 140px; height: 120px;">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/69/Stop_sign(standard).svg" width="140" height="150">
</div>

<p>But... I would like to remove some of the top of the stop sign also - not just the bottom!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

CSS:

```
.target_img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```